# создание объектов из элементов массива

Tags: java

есть класс

```
class SomeClass {
    int firstValue;
    int secondValue;
// getters, constructor, tostring
}
```

и есть строка

```
String txt = "1-2 3-4 5-6 7-8";
```

1-2 один объект, 3-4 второй объект,
надо наделать объектов из строки

```
List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
// разделяю по пробелу и тире
        String[] array = txt.split("\\s*(\\s|-)");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

        if (array.length % 2 == 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i < array.length ; i += 2) {
                list.add(new SomeClass(Integer.parseInt(array[i - 1]), Integer.parseInt(array[i])));
            }
        }
        for (SomeClass s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
//SomeClass{firstValue=1, secondValue=2}
//SomeClass{firstValue=3, secondValue=4}
//SomeClass{firstValue=5, secondValue=6}
//SomeClass{firstValue=7, secondValue=8}
```

подскажите, можно это сделать элегантней через stream или как-нибудь ещё?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пара вариантов:

1. С поочередным разбиением входной строки:

```java
List<SomeClass> list1 = Arrays.stream(txt.split("\\s+"))
    .map(pair -> Arrays.stream(pair.split("-"))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .toArray()
    ) // Stream<int[]>
    .map(arr -> new SomeClass(arr[0], arr[1]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

2. С использованием `IntStream::iterate`:

```java
String[] data = txt.split("\\D+");
List<SomeClass> list2 = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < data.length, i -> i += 2)
    .mapToObj(i -> new SomeClass(
        Integer.parseInt(data[i]), Integer.parseInt(data[i + 1])
    ))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение через stream:

```java
List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
String txt = "1-2 3-4 5-6 7-8";
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
int[] array = Arrays.stream(txt.split("\\s(\\s|-)"))
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
     
if (array.length % 2 == 0) {
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length ; i += 2) {
        list.add(new SomeClass(array[i - 1], array[i]));
    }
}
            
for (SomeClass s : list) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```